# Displaying Cocoa UIComponents without dragging from Interface Builder and making Connections

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview, iboutlet

I have three(can be many) parameters and their values like :

```
School     : Bomey School
Degree     : MBA
Profession : Student
```

I want to display above texts as it is on a view. But suppose the profession is `Lecturer`, I dont want to show the line saying `Degree` at all.

So the profession field should be moved up. For this reason, I cant use the labels and textfields with bindings to populate data on UI.

So how can I populate data like above `dynamically` using code instead of using IB components and connections? The colons should be aligned vertically in single line.

Comment: Isn't it easier to put degree below profession and simply hide it when it isn't needed?

Comment: Ya, initially I thought of doing that way. But as I mentioned, there can be many other fields to be shown among which some in middle should be shown/hidden dynamically.

Comment: You can create the nstextfields by passing the coords from code and setting everything manually

Comment: Can you provide some sample piece of code?